# Module not found Firebase/Rebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, rebase

I'm trying to hook firebase to a website but apparently it can't resolve `firebase/app`. Here are some details :

> ./node_modules/re-base/dist/bundle.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in '********\node_modules\re-base\dist'

and my code look like this :

```js
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    ***: "********************",
    ***: "****************",
    ***: "******************"
})

const base = Rebase.createClass(firebase.database())

export { firebaseApp }
export default base
```

Comment: For more info i tried reinstalling firebase and rebase but i have an error with rebase (even tho i still have it in my nodes_modules) the error is : "404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rebase4.0.0 - Not found "

Comment: can you delete node_modules and package-lock.json and npm i again ?

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Can you try moving the ``firebase/app`` import to the top? "Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first" Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize > Using module bundlers